# How to check if a click event is already in process C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, event-handling, buttonclick

I have a method like this:

```
private async void BtnGivePermit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code here
}
```

And I'm trying to add a button to Cancel and in there I wanted to check if any other click event is not in progress. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: I think we're going to have to see more code than this.  Why is the sample code async?

Comment: raise bool flag at the beginning of method, set it to false at the end?

Comment: Or simply disable the Button, if you need that code to run just once, before a result is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ash suggested, you may want to have a boolean like so:

```
bool isGivePermitProcessing = false;
private void BtnGivePermit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isGivePermitProcessing = true;
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        isGivePermitProcessing = false;
    }
}
```

This will give you a definite understanding of whether the function is currently processing or not.

The `try-finally` block ensures that no exception will cause the `isGivePermitProcessing` boolean to become indefinitely true.

---

Extending the above concept into Jimi's suggestion, you could also simply disable the button like so:

```
private void BtnGivePermit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BtnGivePermit.Enabled = false;
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        BtnGivePermit.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This will also give you a definite understanding of whether the function is currently processing or not while additionally preventing the button from being clicked while already processing a previous click.

---

If you're intending to make a cancel button for asynchronous operations, you might want to look into the [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.8) type.